# UI Appearance setTintColor stops working

Tags: objective-c

The following method is called at the end of `AppDelegate::didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and everything is tinted green as one would expect. But occasional (like three times) the controls all go gray and the App has to be restarted to get the green tint back?

Should I be calling this more often than in App startup?

```
- (void)uiAppearance{

    // Light Green
    UIColor *tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:82/255.0f green:214/255.0f blue:105/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    [[UIButton appearance] setTintColor:tintColor];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:tintColor];
    [[UIImageView appearance] setTintColor:tintColor];
    [[UIActionSheet appearance] setTintColor:tintColor];
    [[UIActionSheet appearance] setTintColor:tintColor];
    [[UIWindow appearance] setTintColor:tintColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App did finish launching will fire only on first installation of your application.
There is no ned to call the method repeatedly, instead of calling it at the end of did finish launching call it from application did become active.
This method will be fired every time you open the app.

Comment: I see it mostly on the iPad and frankly looks like an Apple bug but this is a good idea!